# Changing Linux 'ps' output by changing argv[0]

Tags: linux, centos6, argv, ps

I'm trying to have a program alter what 'ps' displays as the process's CMD name, using the technique I've seen recommended of simply overlaying the memory pointed to by argv[0].  Here is the sample program I wrote.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <linux/prctl.h>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::memcpy;

int main(int argc, char** argv)  {
    if ( argc < 2 ) {
        cout << "You forgot to give new name." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Set new 'ps' command name - NOTE that it can't be longer than
    // what was originally in argv[0]!

    const char *ps_name = argv[1];
    size_t arg0_strlen = strlen(argv[0]);
    size_t ps_strlen = strlen(ps_name);
    cout << "Original argv[0] is '" << argv[0] << "'" << endl;

    // truncate if needed
    size_t copy_len = (ps_strlen < arg0_strlen) ? ps_strlen+1 : arg0_strlen;
    memcpy((void *)argv[0], ps_name, copy_len);
    cout << "New name for ps is '" << argv[0] << "'" << endl;

    cout << "Now spin.  Go run ps -ef and see what command is." << endl;
    while (1) {};
}
```

The output is:

```
$ ./ps_test2 foo
Original argv[0] is './ps_test2'
New name for ps is 'foo'
Now spin.  Go run ps -ef and see what command is.
```

The output of ps -ef is:

```
5079     28952  9142 95 15:55 pts/20   00:00:08 foo _test2 foo
```

Clearly, "foo" was inserted, but its null terminator was either ignored or turned into a blank.  The trailing portion of the original argv[0] is still visible.

How can I *replace* the string that 'ps' prints?

Comment: Chap, what is inside the `/proc/$pid/cmdline` special file? Can you do `hexdump -C` of it?

Comment: 00000000  66 6f 6f 00 5f 74 65 73  74 00 66 6f 6f 00 62 61  |foo._test.foo.ba|
    00000010  72 00                                             |r.|

Comment: @osgx: Well, I can't seem to format it properly, but it corresponds to tetromino's description below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite the entire command line, which in Linux is stored as a contiguous buffer with arguments separated by zeros.

Something like:

```
size_t cmdline_len = argv[argc-1] + strlen(argv[argc-1]) - argv[0];
size_t copy_len = (ps_strlen + 1 < cmdline_len) ? ps_strlen + 1 : cmdline_len;
memcpy(argv[0], ps_name, copy_len);
memset(argv[0] + copy_len, 0, cmdline_len - copy_len);
```

Comment: That appears to be correct.  And I've verified that argv[1..n] point to those null-terminated arguments, which means that I'll end up clobbering argv[1..n].  Something to be aware of.